# Dividir un data frame en hojas de excel

Tags: r

Tengo el siguiente df

```
df <- read.table(text = '
       col1 col2 col3 col4  col5   col6  Cod  ANT    Pep  Tem     Sol
         1   6   11    16     21     26   1    0      1     0       1
         2   7   12    17     22     27   1    0      1     0       0
         3   8   13    18     23     28   0    0      1     0       0
         4   9   14    19     24     29   0    1      1     0       0
         5   10  15    20     25     30   1    0      1     0       1',
header = TRUE, colClasses = "character",stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = 'NA')
```

Quiero pasar ese df a un excel.

Los datos de la col1:col6 + Cod en una hoja del excel llamada Cod, solo los valores con 1.

Los datos de la col1:col6 + ANT en una hoja del excel llamada ANT, solo los valores con 1.

(...)

Los datos de la col1:col6 + Sol en una hoja del excel llamada Sol, solo los valores con 1.

Algo como esto:

```
#Hago tantos df como pestañas va a tener el excel

Cod  <- df[,1:7]
ANT  <- df[,c(1:6,8)]
Pep  <- df[,c(1:6,9)]
Tem  <- df[,c(1:6,10)]
Sol  <- df[,c(1:6,11)]

#Quito los 0, solo me interesan los 1

Cod  <- Cod [ Cod$Cod == 1, ]
ANT  <- ANT [ ANT$ANT == 1, ]
Pep  <- Pep [ Pep$Pep == 1, ]
Tem  <- Tem [ Tem$Tem == 1, ]
Sol  <- Sol [ Sol$Sol == 1, ]

#Meto los df en una lista para poder hacer el excel

lista <- list(Cod, ANT, Pep ,Tem, Sol )
write.xlsx(lista, file.path("prueba2.xlsx"))
```

Ahora habría que renombrar el nombre de las pestañas y ponerles de nombre
Cod, ANT, Pep ,Tem, Sol.

Pues quiero hacer esto con un df con bastantes columnas, y seguro que hay una manera elegante de hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una alternativa de hacer esto es usando lapply. Así sería el código:

```
# Definir las columnas a filtrar
cols <- c("Cod", "ANT", "Pep", "Tem", "Sol")

# Create a list of filtered data frames
df <- lapply(cols , function(col_name) {
  df_filtrado <- df[df[[col_name]] == 1, c(1:6, which(names(df) == col_name))]
  colnames(df_filtrado )[7] <- col_name  # Renombrar las columnas

  return(df_filtrado)

}) |> setNames(cols)

openxlsx::write.xlsx(df, file.path("prueba2.xlsx"))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: perfect!  Se podría cambiar cols <- c("Cod", "ANT", "Pep", "Tem", "Sol") por
cols <- names(df[,7:11]) para ahorrar escribiendo. Gracias!

Comment: Así es, buen punto!